# Form button that runs query that is bound to value in given record field

Tags: ms-access

I have a 2007 Access form, in "continuous format".  I added a button to the “detail" section. Tje purpose of this button is to run a query.    I cant figure out how to make this button’s query  become bound to a field value in the given record. Instead, it runs the query for all records in the table.  Please advise how I can have the query only run based on the value of a specific field for the given record .   Is it possible to accomplish this with out VBA?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter your query to refer to your form. Like so:

```
SELECT ID, Stuff FROM MyTable WHERE ID = Forms!MyForm!ID
```

Where ID is whatever field you choose to match. It will always refer to the line where the button is clicked, because that is the current record.